# Why the solution for checking the validity of binary tree is not working?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm solving a problem to check if a binary tree is valid binary tree. That means the value of the left node of a certain node is smaller and the value of right node is bigger than the node value. The program uses a recursive method to perform the check and return boolean value to determine the validity of the tree. I provided the code as following,

```
class Node {

      Node left;
      Node right; 
       int data;

     public Node(int data_ ){

       this.data = data_;
   }
}

public class myTest{


private static List<Integer> lis = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static List<Integer> inOrder(Node root){

    if (root != null){

        inOrder(root.left);

        lis.add(root.data);
        System.out.println( root.data );
        inOrder(root.right);
    }

    return lis;
}

public static boolean isBST( Node root, int min, int max  ){

    if (root ==  null )
        return true;

    return ( root.data >= min) 
        && ( root.data <= max ) 
        && isBST(root.left, min, root.data) 
        && isBST( root.right, root.data, max );
}

public static void main(String[] args){  

// form the bst
 Node root = new Node(5);
   root.left = new Node(3);
   root.right = new Node(7); 

   root.left.left = new Node(1);
   root.left.right = new Node(2);

   root.right.left = new Node(6);
   root.right.right = new Node(9);

   // get the max and min value from the tree
   int max = 0;
   int min  = 0;

   if (root != null ){

      List<Integer> li  = inOrder(root);
      min =  li.get(0);
      max = li.get( li.size() -1 );
   }


   // determine the validity 
   boolean bol_ = isBST(root, min, max );

   if ( bol_)
     System.out.println("valid BST ");

    else 
        System.out.println("Not valid BST ");
  }

  }
```

The provided test tree is valid but the program tells it isn't. What is the issue inside that I'm not seeing ? Besides, what will be the edge cases to improve the code ? Say, do I need to check if all the values inside the tree are distinct integer and how to do that ?

Comment: Your tree isn't valid, i.e. `root.left.right.data` is smaller than `root.left.data` (2 < 3 ).

Comment: Oops, I see that now, thanks for mentioning. Do you see any edge cases or any suggestions to improve the code ?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't thoroughly read the code but I'll try to share a few observations: 1) I'd not make use of static methods like `inOrder()` in combination with static variables like `lis`, I'd either pass the list as a parameter or make both instance vars. 2) One could argue that `node.left.data == node.data` might not represent a valid tree since this might indicate that a node and its left (or right) child are the same. At least you should check for that.

Comment: I agree about passing the List<Integer> parameter as you said. BTW, where I'm doing this node.left.data == node.data  ?

Comment: You're not doing that explicitly but you're checking `root.data >= min` etc. where `min` might implicitly be the value of the parent node. I'd rather just check for lower and greater and upon the initial call I'd just pass `min - 1` and `max + 1`.

Comment: Sounds better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas pointed out, your tree is not a valid BST.

However I wanted to give you some advice. There is a lot of edge cases when you are trying to evaluate if a tree is a binary tree or not recursively. One simpler solution would be to traverse the tree in order, store the elements in an ArrayList, then check to see if the list is sorted. This implementation is much easier/simpler and also runs in the same time complexity but with a bigger space complexity: O(n) for both.

Comment: I think you point out a solution which is good. As you see in my code, I'm also making an ArrayList of inOrderTraverse values and I can use that method for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this:

root.left = new Node(3);
root.left.right = new Node(2);
-> on right side there must be value higher then root - like this

root.left = new Node(2);
root.left.right = new Node(3);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, the reason I'm not accepting as this is pointed out earlier by @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method little and now it goes as following,

```
public static boolean isBST( Node root, int min, int max  ){

    if (root ==  null )
        return true;

    return ( root.data > min) 
        && ( root.data < max ) 
        && isBST(root.left, min, root.data) 
        && isBST( root.right, root.data, max );
}
```

While the calling is as follow,

```
boolean bol_ = isBST(root, min - 1 , max +1 );
```